# Why does picins exist in MikTeX but it does not exist in TeX Live?

Tags: packages, texlive, miktex, licensing, picins

If picins is not free, why does it exist in MikTeX?

Comment: TexLive's team is strict, only packages with a certain kind of licence are accepted in TL.
MikTeX and TeXLive are not equivalent. picins is free but I think it's a problem of licence

Comment: Note that *in theory* the licence conditions for inclusion in MikTeX are the same as for TeX Live, according to the first paragraph of <http://miktex.org/copying> (compare with <http://www.tug.org/texlive/LICENSE.TL>). However, examples such as this one show that this common policy is not as actively enforced in MikTeX as in TeX Live.

Comment: And btw picins is *not* free for *any* commonly accepted definition of free/libre software since you cannot modify it without author's permission *and* it doesn't even have a licence statement about distribution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be due to licensing issues and the package author being unavailable. See the following thread and especially the post in the link: [[tex-live] picins is missing from tex-live](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2007-December/015186.html) .

Also, on why it's in MikTeX. [On their homepage](http://miktex.org/packages/picins) it doesn't say anything about the license of picins (it's silent about version and maintainer too). So, to connect with a comment above, it seems they are not as strict as TeX Live when it comes to these things.