# How can I prevent the next paragraph from overwriting the image of a description label?

Tags: spacing, floats, description, wrap, pandoc

LaTeX code generated from [MarkDown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) by [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth
\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\makeatother
\let\Oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\Oldincludegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{#1}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% begin custom preamble
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{style=multiline, leftmargin=4.2cm}

\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
    \vspace{-\fontcharht\font`(}#1
    \end{minipage}
}
% end custom preamble

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt
\item[\includegraphics{example-image}]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{description}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Results in:
[image: next paragraph overlaps with description label image]

### Question

I would like to have automatic vertical separation with the next paragraph, **only by changing the preamble**, not the main document. (Remember, it is code automatically generated by [**Pandoc**](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html)!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end, perseverance pays off. Here is a solution based on `floatflt` that does wrap the next paragraph properly by only changing the preamble. One of the tricks is in the `\hspace{0pt}`.

The issue of clearing the float is dealt with [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130634/how-to-measure-the-vertical-space-that-was-typeset-without-placing-it-into-an-en) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130665/26348).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth
\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\makeatother
\let\Oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\Oldincludegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{#1}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% begin preamble.tex
\usepackage{floatflt}
\renewenvironment{description}{%
    \renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\vspace{-1ex}\Oldincludegraphics[width=4cm]{##1}}
    \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{##1\end{floatingfigure}}%
    \hspace{0pt}%
    \begin{floatingfigure}[l]{4cm}}%
    {}
% end preamble.tex

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt
\item[\includegraphics{example-image-a}]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{description}

\blindtext

\begin{description}
\itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt
\item[\includegraphics{example-image-b}]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{description}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: floatflt solution]

### Remark

It took me (on and off) almost a week to come up with this answer. Compare that to the mere three seconds to issue a `{float: left}` in order to achieve the same with CSS for the HTML document generated from the same [Pandoc MarkDown](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html). This made me really appreciative of questions like these:

- [CSS based LaTeX formatting?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35606/css-based-latex-formatting)
- [Why couldn't (La)TeX's layout model be as simple as CSS's layout model?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6461/why-couldnt-latexs-layout-model-be-as-simple-as-csss-layout-model)

Comment: The solution is not compatible (yet?) with `\usepackage[nobottomtitles*]{titlesec}` in the preamble.

Answer (score 7):

It would be possible to make the list environment aware of the image depth, but it is easier to use `wrapfig` I show two variants, carrying the indent into the following paragraph, or moving the following paragraph down,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe,wrapfig}

\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth
\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\makeatother
\let\Oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\Oldincludegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{#1}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

% Solution 1    
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{4cm}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.

\blindtext

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

% Solution 2
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{4cm}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like the first solution. The problem is my LaTeX file is generated by [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html). Hence, I can only change the preamble. I am now trying to put your solution inside a `\renewenvironment{description}`, but I am struggling.

Comment: Because of the limitations imposed by the use of [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html), a solution where the list environment is made aware of the image depth sounds very interesting. As a matter of fact, this is what I originally hoped for. By the way, Pandoc is needed since it also generates a nice HTML version starting from the same MarkDown source.

Comment: What a pity that [the `picins` package is not distributed with the TeXLive distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20174/why-does-picins-exist-in-miktex-but-it-does-not-exist-in-tex-live). `\parpic` is namely the only wrapping command fully compatible with list environments. It probably would have been a nice and easy solution.

Comment: @on4aa -- perhaps you could persuade the developer of `picins` to modify it to use the lppl, and provide complete documentation.  those appear to be the two criteria that prevent it from being included in tex live.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution exclusively based on minipages, height measuring and preamble gymnastics. The only limitation is that it does not wrap, but properly clears space for the images and following paragraph. Nevertheless, I posed [a follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130482/how-can-i-redefine-a-list-item-to-normal-text-in-order-to-enable-proper-wrapping) in an attempt to achieve real wrapping under these constraints.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth
\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\makeatother
\let\Oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\Oldincludegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{#1}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% begin preamble.tex
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\imgheight

\renewenvironment{description}{%
    \renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\Oldincludegraphics[width=4cm]{##1}}
    \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{%
        \settototalheight\imgheight{##1}%
        \global\imgheight=\imgheight%
        ##1%
        \end{minipage}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t][\imgheight][s]{\dimexpr\linewidth-4.2cm}
        }
    \begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
    \vspace{-\fontcharht\font`(}%
    }%
    {%
    \par\vfill%
    \end{minipage}}
% end preamble.tex

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt
\item[\includegraphics{example-image-a}]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{description}

\blindtext

\begin{description}
\itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt
\item[\includegraphics{example-image-b}]
\blindtext
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]